# db.key() function to a string representation and back

Tags: python, django, key

I've used [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) example to to implement some sort of guestbook, only I'm using django framework.
I can't use db.key() function in the html file so I thought maybe I should pass the html with the string representation of the key and by this solve this issue. I checked the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key) and it says

> A key can be converted to a string by passing the Key object to str().

so I've used :

```
all_messages = db.GqlQuery( "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20" ,  image_key('name'))
    for msg in all_messages:
        msg.img_key_func = str(msg.key())
```

is this the correct way to convert key to string?

my html looks like this:

```
<ol name="list">
    {% for message in all_messages %}
    <li><div><img src="img?img_id={{ message.img_key_func }}"></img>{{ message.content }}</div></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

What i need to do is simply something like this example:

```
            self.response.out.write("<div><img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" %
                                      greeting.key())
```

the outcome of the logs is:  /img?img_id=None  and thus, I cant display the images.

is there an easier way to do this?
Thanx!

**EDIT 1:**  more info

the submit button triggers

> class Sender(webapp.RequestHandler):

with the following:

```
def post(self):
    accountName = self.request.get( "accountName" )
    text = self.request.get( "text" )
    message = Messages(parent=image_key('name'))
    message.content = self.request.get( "text" )
    avatar = self.request.get('img')
    if avatar:
        avatar = images.resize(self.request.get("img"), 32, 32)
        image_full = self.request.get("img")
        message.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
        message.imageblob = db.Blob(image_full)
    message.put()
```

the Messages(db.Model) looks like:

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    imageblob = db.BlobProperty()
    avatar = db.BlobProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


    def image_key(some_id='name'):
        return db.Key.from_path('StartPage', 'name')
```

the question is,Should I store the avatar right after download Or I should resize very time a get_main_page is requested? this way I can avoid storing 2 images -one full size and another avatar.
should i still use image_key?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the key() function in your template (`...img_id={{ message.key }}">...`). If you're seeing `/img?img_id=None` the most likely reason is that msg.key() returned None...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> I can't use db.key() function in the html file

is not true. You can use any functions or methods that don't take arguments in a template. So, as thebjorn pointed out in the comment, this would work fine:

```
img_id="{{ message.key }}"
```

because the template language would call the `key()` method and then convert it to string for output.

Comment: Well, you both right. now i can have the key from the html, the only problem is I get 404 on a image that has just uploaded.  This the log output from GAE: "GET /img?img_id=ahJzfnRzdC1wdXNoLXByb2FwcHNyIgsSCVN0YXJ0UGFnZSIEbmFtZQwLEghNZXNzYWdlcxjBPgw HTTP/1.1" 404 124 "http://xxxxxx.appspot.com/ "